# What is statelessness in REST API in layman term?

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, stateless, stateful

I have gone through various REST API documentation. However, I don't have a clear understanding of it. Can someone help me to understand it in layman's terms? How is it different from API being stateful? Why today all the APIs we develop are restful APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Term stateless/stateful is a common term and has the same meaning for Rest API as for anything else.

1. Stateless means that when you make a call to some entity the response (output) will always depend on your input only. I.e. for any number of calls with the same input you will ALWAYS get the same response. Example: a request of "what is 2 + 2 equals to?" will always get you an answer 4 no matter how many times you ask and regardless if there were other queries in-between your query requests.
2. Stateful means that the output will depend on your input and some internal state. Example: "Please add 2 to current number that you hold. what is the new number?" (Assuming that the internal state (the current number) is 0). after the first query you will get the answer 2 but after the same query for the second time you will get answer 4 and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Today we use JSON Web Token to call API which contains all the information be it authentication and authorization. Could you please help me to understand this context? A long time ago we used to use sessions.

Comment: @SwetaSharma I don't understand your question that you asked in your comment. If you ask how tokens help you to differentiate between different users/sessions just google it.

Comment: @SwetaSharma - with sessions you are following a stateful paradigm, ie the server keeps track of who the user is and his state, ie whether he is authenticated, what his roles are. In the stateless paradigm the server does not keep information between requests about the user and roles etc. This info is passed to the server on EVERY request (usually in a JWT) and the server extracts it on each request and uses the info. The advantage of this over stateful is scalability. Each server in a cluster can work on it's own without overheads like session replication.

Comment: One thing i don't understand. REST is all about dealing with resources (create, update and delete). As long as the request contains all the information, which server can rely on to handle the resources, that will be considered REST.  Since we use session to keep track of login state (including CSRF token, or whatever),  that has nothing to do with the resource handling, so why would we not allowed to have session then?   
Hence from this perspective, i personally feel that Roy Fielding should  amend his dissertion that server session is only for non-resource handling related info.

Answer (score 0):

> Each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)

Note that this is a constraint on *semantics*: all of the information that you need to understand the meaning of the request is in the request itself.

Counter example: the LIST command in [FTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959), where a null argument for pathname "implies the user's current working or default directory" is *not* stateless -- current working directory is data of session state that the server needs to remember from previous requests.